# Gnome animations are not working on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

I installed Gnome on Debian stretch stable, with kernel version 4.18 from `stretch-backports`, and after logging in, the animations usually present on Gnome do not work, i.e. apps sliding into the applications menu, the blur on the bar at the top of the screen. However, if I go to a `tty`, then type `startx`, the Gnome desktop environment starts and the animations works. I have looked around, but haven't found any answers as to why this is happening, or how it can be fixed. Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

I am starting Gnome via the graphics login screen, GDM, and am using an X11 session. I'm using a Core i5-8400 with Intel UHD Graphics 630.

Comment: Hi @wispi. What is your graphic card? Did you update the drivers after installation?

Comment: How are you starting your session? Via GDM? Are you trying to start a Wayland session? Try to click on the little gear in GDM and see if it's a X11 session or a Wayland session you are trying to start

Comment: @Goro I'm using an Intel Core i5-8400 with Intel UHD graphics 630, not a discrete graphics card. After some research, it seems that Debian already contains the necessary packages for Intel Graphics (xserver-xorg-video-intel). When using kernel 4.8, the default Debian stable kernel version, the resolution was stuck at 1024 x 768, but after updating the kernel to 4.18, it allowed me to set the correct resolution. When, for example, watching videos on YouTube in 4k, the content looks fine and the frame rate looks proper, so I think the problem is with Gnome, and not the drivers or GPU.

Comment: @Bigon I'm starting Gnome with GDM (the Gnome login screen), and using Gnome on System X11. If I try to login with Wayland, the animations work, but are choppy.

Comment: Are you using systemd? Do you have a logind session registered when you open your session? You can check with the `loginctl` command

Comment: @Bigon Yes it seems I do have a logind session. The output of loginctl lists my username under `USER`. Can I ask for clarification as to what you mean relating to `systemd`?

Comment: @Goro Using `gconf-editor`, I only see the folders 'apps' and 'schemas' under '/'. I tried disabling then enabling animations with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations [true/false]` but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: If you want to try all the options, there is a weird compromise one no-one has mentioned yet :-). See the package description of `xserver-xorg-video-intel`. "The use of this driver is discouraged if your hw is new enough (ca. 2007 and newer). You can try uninstalling this driver and let the server use it's builtin modesetting driver instead."

Comment: A logind session is needed so your user has access to the needed devices (/dev) to talk to the graphic card

Answer (score 0):

Given that the animations are working from the command line. Try to appended the following lines in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
su - <username> - c startx
exit 0
```

Comment: This is a bad idea especially as GDM will already start and I would suggest to keep GDM

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I still want to have the proper Gnome login screen.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by installing and using vanilla-gnome-desktop on my ubuntu 18.04